# GENERAR NUMEROS RANDOM EN UN VECTOR N JAVA

Tags: java, array

noches compañeros, estoy aprendiendo programación, 
así que estoy batallando con algo. Mi problema es de que tengo un vector y le pido n numeros.

Pero mi problema actual es de que por ejemplo si quiero pedirle 1000 numeros a mi programa, quiero que me dé numeros aletorios del rango de 0 a 1000,

o si le inserto 10,000 numeros que me de los de del 0 al 10,000

si son 150,000 mil que me los de del 0 a ese rango etc etc..

Cómo podría hacer eso con el Randon, ya intenté pero no me funciona, ya que  gracias y saludos!

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Qué problema has tenido? Pon algo de tu código para ponernos en contexto y saber cómo ayudarte lo mejor posible.

Answer (score 0):

aqui tienes el codigo, he decidido usar arrarys de tipo `[]`  porque si desde el comienzo vas a saber su tamaño pues va a ser un poco mas eficiente. Cualquier duda comenta mi respuesta

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


public class Stack_generar_random_en_vector {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int tamañoArray = 0;
        int[] array  = null;

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            System.out.println("Introduce el tamaño que quieres que tenga el array");
            System.out.print("->");
            //este sera el tamaño del array
             tamañoArray = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
             array = new int[tamañoArray];
            //definamos ahora los posibles numeros randoms

            int M = 0; //minimo posible
            int N = tamañoArray ; //maximo posible

            //ahora rellenamos el array con esos numeros aleatorios
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                int valorAleatorio = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * (N - M + 1) + M);  // Valor entre M y N, ambos incluidos.
                array[i] = valorAleatorio;

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error "+e);
        }


        //ahora hacemos display de los valores para comprobar que haya funcionado

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

            System.out.println(array[i]);
        }
    }

}
```